# OpenCV Streaming formats

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to stream in video to my Linux machine. On the Linux side I'm using OpenCV. I tried to find a list of supported codecs but couldn't find any.

Where can I find a list of supported codecs that can be used with open CV?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs):

> The mencoder video encoder is an open source video encoder which is
>   available on Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux. To convert existing videos
>   to the I420 format supported by OpenCV on all platforms, install the
>   mencoder binary and use:
>
> $ mencoder in.avi -ovc raw -vf format=i420 -o out.avi

Looks like the I420 format is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use opencv for showing streamed content so I need to use codec like H264 or something like this.

Comment: A C++ example of how to convert programmatically: http://barnesc.blogspot.com/2007/04/opencv-camera-and-avi-input.html